# How to change Log out icon in jazzmin django theme?

Tags: python, django

I have django project with jazzmin theme library I use, I've change icon for sidebar with:

```
"icons:{...}"
```

[image]

and I want to change the user menu icons, the logout menu:

[image]

what I know is, we can use this line:

```
"usermenu_links" : {}
```

But I don't quite understand how to pointing for the log out button, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and the simple steps are
*copy the base template from **env>lib** and save that in local project*
[template-folder example in djnago](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMXpg.png)
then you can edit logout icon and more.
[vs-code base template image screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCdNa.png)